# ASP.NET Model Binding and ignoring model attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, annotations

I'm using ASP.NET Model Binding to show my data in forms. For example in following code I list items of the type Models.Region :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterRegions"
    ItemType="Models.Region"
    SelectMethod="regionsRepeater_GetData">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="ReadOnly" UIHint="TableHeader"/>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="ReadOnly"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This code works pretty well but in some cases and models I would like to see only subset of the model properties.

I tried to use some DataAnnotations but I can't find any to ignore some properties in Model Binding. Attribute

```
[BindableTypeAttribute(IsBindable = false)]
```

is possible to use only for class not for properties.

Do you have any idea how to deal with this scenario?